# Display a limit of 15 elements taken from MySQL (while I am forced to use a LIMIT above 15)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a list of 15 profiles pictures from my members.

There is a column called `settings`, which looks like `0, 1, 1, 1`

I must only display the pictures of someone who has a `1` as the first number above.

Since I can't directly fetch people `WHERE the first number`is 1, I must fetch everybody regardless of the number. I will then only display the people who have 1 set. (any way to solve the problem right here in the query?)

About 20% of my members have a `0` as this number, so in my query, I have to set a `LIMIT` higher than 15 (I set it at 30 now, else at 15 I would have a list with less than 15 pictures).

However, I must display exactly 15 people in the list, and it often ends up between 15-30 (because limit = 30).

I tried using for / while loops but I'm not sure where to place it.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT picture_path, profile_picture, username, last_visit, signup_date, settings FROM tusers 
                WHERE profile_picture IS NOT NULL 
                AND sex = 1 
                AND  last_visit BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 DAY AND CURDATE() 
                AND signup_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY 
                ORDER BY RAND()
                LIMIT 30");
    $query->execute();
    $members_results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($members_results as $key => $member) {
        $meet_new_people_enabled = explode(",", $member['settings']);

        if ($meet_new_people_enabled[0] == '1') {
            $picture_path = "http://www.mySite.com/" . $member['picture_path'] . "/" . $member['profile_picture']; 
            echo '<figure class="member"><a href="' . $member['username'] . '"><img src="' . $picture_path . '" title="' . $member['settings'] . '" width="100" height="100" /></a></figure>';
        }
    }
```

How would you solve this so exactly 15 people are displayed?

Thank you

Comment: Could you use wildcard sql filter "WHERE (settings like '1,%' or settings='1')" selecting only those having first or only number 1 in a column string. It might blow sql index away but am not sure about that.

Comment: Maybe normalize your data?

Comment: You should really separate those comma separated numbers into new columns, if it's a serious project I can see you struggling with the queries as it gets more complex, I think the design of the database is quite important, will have a great impact on the performance and development stage of your project

Comment: Whome -- Thanks! should've thought of that.
@Strawberry -- The DB was designed like that, but I'll probably have to improve it if the queries are getting too slow.

Comment: @aleation one column per number would be an improvement but this really should be done with a dependant table and foreign key.

Comment: @GordonM I agree, at least partially, depending on the size and the values, sometimes it's quicker/more comfortable just adding a column imo, I should have say "You should at least separate..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing your data wrong.

The cardinal rule of database design (more formally known as first normal form or 1NF) is that every column should hold 1 AND ONLY 1 piece of data (more formally, all data must be atomic).

CSV data is, by its nature, not atomic.  It's a number of values stored in a list delimited by commas.  If you have such data you'll have difficulty manipulating and querying it, as you've just discovered.

You should normalize you data by putting the data in the settings column in a dependant table and associating it with a row in the primary table with a foreign key.

If this is not an option, you should at least have a column for each setting value.